# Check whether Hazelcast cluster is ready for requests via bash

Tags: bash, curl, wget, hazelcast, netcat

I'm using [Docker with Hazelcast 3.6](https://hub.docker.com/r/hazelcast/hazelcast/).
I launch Hazelcast instances and want to launch my application only after cluster is ready for requests.

I've read in [documentation](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/restclient.html), that it's possible to access Hazelcast via `curl`, but it doesn't work for me.
I'm getting `(52) Empty reply from server`, when trying to `POST` to Hazelcast instance, which is started and ready.

Is there a method to check, whether Hazelcast is ready?
E.g., for Cassandra I run
`wget --spider 0.0.0.0:9042`
for RabbitMQ this one works great `netcat -z -w 2 rabbit 5672`. Is there similar solution for Hazelcast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [REST API for cluster management](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#using-rest-api-for-cluster-management), which described in the documentation.
Another hint, you can use `cluster.sh` script in `bin` directory to interact with management endpoints.

You're trying to hit a [REST client API](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.6/manual/html-single/index.html#rest-client) (for accessing maps and queues), which is disabled by default.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you

Comment: thank you for quick response! I tried to run hazelcast management center, but the main page shown me `404`. Another problem is: I didn't actually try to connect it with my cluster. Do I need management-center to use your proposition, or it's another thing? I tried to execute `curl http://hazelcast:5701/hazelcast/rest/management/cluster/state` from my Docker with Hazelcast &mdash; got Bad Request, and Hazelcast logs contain `Connection lost. Reason: java.io.EOFException[Remote socket closed!]`. Seems like I should get `cluster.sh` script and work with it

Comment: management API doesn't require management center. Management center is a separate web application that you can find in `mancenter` folder of Hazelcast installation. There you can find startup scripts as well.

Comment: regarding `bad request`. you need to provide a set of the parameters to connect to the cluster including `groupname` and  `password`.

Comment: ```echo "Getting cluster state on ip ${ADDRESS} on port ${PORT}"
 request="http://${ADDRESS}:${PORT}/hazelcast/rest/management/cluster/state"
  response=$(curl --data "${GROUPNAME}&${PASSWORD}" --silent "${request}");
    STATUS=$(echo "${response}" | sed -e 's/^.*"status"[ ]*:[ ]*"//' -e 's/".*//');``` from `cluster.sh`

Comment: Got it! I didn't setup my group and password http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/createclustergroups.html. I thought, that it's about some unix user group, but it's a Hazelcast cluster group. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

**Caution**: **Don't forget** to hide group name and password when using public CI and/or code repository if you don't need all people to see this data.

- first of all I had to add cluster group in configuration, see [Creating Cluster Groups](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/createclustergroups.html) in documentation;
- then use `curl --data "${GROUPNAME}&${PASSWORD}" http://${ADDRESS}:${PORT}/hazelcast/rest/management/cluster/state` to wait until cluster is ready.

E.g., in my case, when Hazelcast listens on `0.0.0.0:5701` with group name `app1` and password `app1-pass`, it looks as follows

```
curl --data "app1&app1-pass" \
     http://0.0.0.0:5701/hazelcast/rest/management/cluster/state
```

### Note

As I understood, it will not show, whether all nodes are ready, so I need to check them separately.
When I set `hazelcast.initial.min.cluster.size` to `2`, main node shows message `HazelcastInstance waiting for cluster size of 2` and `curl` returns `{"status":"success","state":"active"}`.